# angularfire signInWithPopup failing to load

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am building an angular SPA with firebase integration, using angularfire.
I have the signInWithPopup authentication working, but when I add the router functionality the sign in popup fails with the warning (in Firefox):

> Loading failed for the  with source “https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb217841”.

I have seen in this thread [auth/network-request-failed with Google signInWithPopup](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/22) that this could be a problem with /__ namespace.

How can we detect if the router is using such a namespace ?

My app-root HTML:

```
<app-main-header></app-main-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am "inflating" my header and below is the router which is working fine. When I try to sign in with the Google popup the error shows off and the page is reloaded.

Any thoughts ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry everybody, I had made a huge mistake, and a silly one. This was my login button:

```
<li><a href="#" *ngIf="!goodToGo" (click)="loginUser()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

The href="#" argument was redirecting the router and "killing" the sign in popup. Removing it solved the problem.